# Bibliography for learning partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to learn partial differential equations for a job. Are there any online resources (books or tutorials) good enough to learn how to solve partial differential of all kinds (homogeneous, linear &&  nonĺineal). I am not limited to use only online resources, if you know of a good book which I can purchase, I will buy it. But please, it must be about solving partial differential equtions in general .

Thanks in advance,
Cheers.

Comment: You'll need to add more to your post for anyone to help. You haven't made it clear what prior mathematics you have learnt, nor have you specified _how_ you want to solve said PDEs (numerically, analytically etc).

Comment: Since this is for work, you don't need a book that's too theoretical. I recommend Strauss.  You could also check out Boyce and DiPrima, which has a few chapters on PDEs. I agree with Mattos that if you're going to be solving PDES numerically, that makes a big difference. You could learn to implement some finite difference methods for solving PDES very quickly, without reading very much about theory. For numerically solving PDEs, Strikwerda is one good book to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks !! Besides work, I also would like to learn the theory behind the solutions. I am a mathematician and I took some time ago a course about ordinary differential equations. I know basic calculus and analysis.

Comment: And linear algebra of course

Comment: For PDE theory, Evans is a very popular textbook.  I also recommend [McOwen](https://www.amazon.com/Partial-Differential-Equations-Methods-Applications/dp/0130093351).  But my opinion is that even if one is ultimately interested in theory, it's nice to start with a book like [Strauss](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470054565/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_2?pf_rd_p=1944687682&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0130093351&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=3J4QF1WM1H07PF9QWP80) where everything seems a little simpler.